# Load data from Oracle into Sybase IQ

Tags: oracle, odbc, informatica, sap-iq

How can I load data from Oracle (11g EE R11.2.0.3.0 64bit) into Sybase IQ (15.4.0.3027 64bit) with acceptable speed?

For Initial data load, data is pushed via Sybase Loader as bulk. This works fine.
But after that, data (eg. new data, changes, deleted data) is pushed to Sybase via ODBC (performing Inserts, Updates and Deletes. And there are on Sybase also PK, FK, index constraints to be met). This runs at an average speed of 5 rows per second.  As you may imagine, this is simply too slow. So I need to think of other options. 
Do you have any experience with this kind of problem and what workaround could do the trick? Is there a way to tune ODBC? Or will I have to bluk insert into a temp table on Sybase and then perform a merge on Sybase side? Or is the best option to always trunc Sybase and bulk insert afterwards? BTW: the tool used for the push is Informatica PowerCenter v9.5.1 HotFix1 0315 204. May this also cause issues? I am open to any ideas.

Comment: Just at the first glance: bulk mode 'ignores' indexes and constraints. So in order to compare PowerCenter and ODBC vs bulk, you should first test loading data with all the indexes and constraints removed. Only if the performance improvement will not be significant, then you can lean towards ODBC and other things (eg. network throughput from IS to Sybase). If you'll see an improvement, then your next steps would be to analyze indexing (removing obsolete ones; perhaps dropping and recreating them would help) and use other techniques like partitioning.

Comment: "Just at the first glance: bulk mode 'ignores' indexes and constraints." incorrect. Sybase loader does move the data into the table ignoring constraints. But after all data is in the table it does validate all constraints. If just one is violated, the whole table is rolled back again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Still, you are comparing bulk mode vs normal mode (to use PowerCenter terminology), so this is not ODBC's fault (at least: not yet for sure). Compare to loading with the indexes removed, this should put some light on the problem.